# Modify SQL query by adding range sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query and am unable to get a result from it, the area is 8 digit range am trying to have the quantity in area start with range 1P[01-99]Kxxx

```
select 
    label 
    , coalesce (sum(case when left(area,5) ='1P__K' then quantity end), 0) as '1P_K'
from my_table with (nolock) 
group by label
```

Sample Table :

| Label | Area | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | 1p01k458 | 10 |
| L1 | 1p58K874 | 20 |
| L1 | 1p96k786 | 30 |
| L1 | 1p99k785 | 40 |

Expected Result :

| Label | 1P_K |
| --- | --- |
| L1 | 100 |

Looking forwards to your kind help

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. (As you were asked on your previous question).

Comment: just rearrange your query.     select 
        label 
        , sum(quantity) as '1P_K'
    from my_table 
    where left(area,5) ='1P__K'
    group by label -- Hope it will help

Comment: @DaleK, a sample table had been added, appreciate your advice

Comment: [Bad habits: putting `nolock` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @LearnHadoop, am looking to use the same existing query as it will help for different purpose

Comment: @DaleK, may i know why it's a bat habit? i've been trained to use it when i query in sql server, and honestly i don't know why i use it

Comment: @DaleK :1p96k786 was corrected, it was a mistype

Comment: I think you want `left(area,5) LIKE '1P__K'` instead of `left(area,5) ='1P__K'`. Alternately, you could use `stuff(left(area,5), 3, 2, '')` to remove the middle characters and either test for `stuff(left(area,5), 3, 2, '') = '1PK'` or rewrite your query to `GROUP BY stuff(left(area,5), 3, 2, '')`.

Comment: select lab,
  sum(
    case when left(area,5) like '1p__k' then qty else 0 end
  )
  ,
  sum(qty)
  from your_table
  group by lab

Comment: @TN would pls explain  stuff(left(area,5), 3, 2, '') what 3,2 & '' means ?

Comment: `STUFF()` selects a fragment of the input string (first parameter) and replaces it with another fragment. The `3, 2` is the start and length, which would be the [00-99] portion for your data. By providing an empty replacement, the effect is to just remove that portion of the string. That together with the `LEFT()` would transform `'1p01k458'` into just `'1pk'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change `=` to `like` as equals requires an exact match whereas you want a similar match.

```
case when left(area,5) like '1P__K' then quantity else 0 end
```

Or you could continue to use wildcards and remove `left` e.g.

```
case when area like '1P__K%' then quantity else 0 end
```

Works as follows:

```
declare @Test table ([Label] varchar(2), Area varchar(12), QTY int);

insert into @Test ([Label], Area, QTY)
values
('L1', '1p01k458', 10),
('L1', '1p58K874', 20),
('L1', '1p96k786', 30),
('L1', '1p99k785', 40),
('L1', '1q99k785', 30), -- row that doesn't match the criteria
('L2', '1p58K874', 22), -- row for different area
('L2', '1p96k786', 35);

select 
    [label]
    -- Solution 1 
    , sum(case when left(Area,5) like '1P__K' then QTY else 0 end) as '1P_K'
    -- Solution 2 
    , sum(case when Area like '1P__K%' then QTY else 0 end) as '1P_K'
from @Test 
group by label;
```

Returning

| label | 1P_K | 1P_K |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | 100 | 100 |
| L2 | 57 | 57 |

Note: adding the sample data as DDL+DML (as I have) makes it much easier to answer. Also I've added an additional row which should be excluded by your matching logic - because its important to test such cases. And added another area to prove that that also works.